# Bluetooth connection failed in HTC incredable device android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-wireless

i am developing an android application with bluetooth connectivity. Here i used below code to connect socket.

```
BluetoothSocket mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
```

This is working fine for all the devices but not working for HTC devices. 
So i used another code for connecting socket for only htc device which is described below.

Connection is establishing fine for some time but after some time connection is going lost.

```
Method m = mmDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
mmSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(mmDevice, 1);
```

This is my Logcat while bluetooth connection lost

```
04-18 12:21:04.962: E/BB_LOGS(4285): disconnected
04-18 12:21:04.962: E/BB_LOGS(4285): java.io.IOException: Software caused connection abort
04-18 12:21:04.962: E/BB_LOGS(4285):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readNative(Native Method)
04-18 12:21:04.962: E/BB_LOGS(4285):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.read(BluetoothSocket.java:333)
04-18 12:21:04.962: E/BB_LOGS(4285):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothInputStream.read(BluetoothInputStream.java:96)
04-18 12:21:04.962: E/BB_LOGS(4285):    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
04-18 12:21:04.962: E/BB_LOGS(4285):    at com.fitness.BluetoothService$ConnectedThread.run(BluetoothService.java:592)
```

Please advice me a working procedure for connection bluetooth code for htc all devices

Comment: Why is this tagged Core-Bluetooth? Core-Bluetooth is a iOS framework for Bluetooth Low-Energy. Are you trying to use Bluetooth Low Energy to connect an iDevice with an Android one? Which should be "possible" only with Motorola ones since there is no Android Framework for Bluetooth Low Energy.

Comment: Thanks for responding me @Larme.We are trying to fetch data from some hardware device which have the bluetooth functionality. My first socket connection is woking fine for all devices except htc devices.

Comment: So, it has nothing to do with iOS and/or Bluetooth Low Energy?

Comment: Yes. Here i need a procedure for bluetooth socket connecing for all device.Please can you advice me.

Comment: What I'm saying, is that you tagged your question with CoreBluetooth! It's only for Bluetooth Low Energy on iOS! And I think that isn't what you're looking for, since Android doesn't really support it. So I untag it. I know nothing about Android Bluetooth, so I can't help you more.